Using "Promotional Content" for In-App Purchase Discounts in Google Play Store
Google Play Console offers the capability to set up events and promotions under "Store Presence > Promotional Content". I'm interested in creating a promotional offer for an in-app purchase. While I can establish the promotional event via "Promotional Content", I'm unclear on how to implement the discount itself. Is there a more efficient way to apply a discount across all countries without manually changing the in-app item's price for each one? Given the variation in pricing across different countries, this approach is quite cumbersome. What is the recommended method for executing this?
